# Yamaha DTX Multi-12 drum pad SW/HW hack

Tags: hardware

I have a Yamaha DTX Multi-12 drum pad. It's great, but its fatal design flaw is it doesn't support samples over ~5 sec/ ~100 KB. I would love to be able to import pop-song-length CD-quality samples (+5 min. @ 192 Kbps).

I don't really know where to start with this. My first guess: Find a compatible 16GB+ SSD 2.5" hard drive, attach it to the motherboard, then tweak the software so it can recognize and accept importing larger file sizes/longer sample lengths. How you *actually* do all that is beyond me.

Anyone have any insight into a fairly advanced project like this? Thanks!

Comment: lack of memory would be one limitation and address space.

Comment: @Chris how do you plan to 'tweek' the software if you don't have a copy of the source? Reverse engineering software is time consuming, like years of work

Comment: If you have a MIDI output then I would look to see if you can use an external device (PC with open software) to do the recording.  The file size limitations would go away and the sample rates may be easy to achieve with modern hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the software can be 'tweaked' since it's built in some flash/EEPROM and cannot be edited.

The most easiest way is probably to use an external sampler, assuming your Yamaha DTX has MIDI output. Modern samplers (or even by using a laptop with MIDI interface) can give very long samples.

But of course this would 'spoil' the project.

Comment: Getting an external sampler is probably the path of least resistance. I was hoping to pimp out the DTX so it behaved more like its main competitor, the Roland SPD-SX, which can process long samples like a champ.

Comment: I'm afraid that changing firmware is almost impossible to do. Since you would need not only the specs of all components, but also find a way to reprogram the flash (and creating ALL software yourself). Building a new one yourself might be easier.